# Sorting CSS code ascending

Tags: css, sorting, optimization, stylesheet, notepad++

I am triying to sort my CSS code, But no luck.
I have a CSS code of more then 2000 lines, so it is not possible to sort them manually.

For example I want to sort this:

```
#sidebar{color:#aaa}
body{font-size:20px}
#sidebar .h3{color:#555}
footer{border:solid 1px #eee}
```

... into this:

```
body{font-size:20px}
footer{border:solid 1px #eee}
#sidebar{color:#aaa}
#sidebar .h3{color:#555}
```

Is there any plugin for notepad++ or any online site for doing this?

Comment: You are probably looking for CSS minification: try http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: I think you mean 'sort'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a plugin for Notepad++ if you want to sort:

1. Menu => Plugins => Plugin Manager => Show Plugin Manager
2. Available => `TextFX Characters` => Press `Install` and restart Notepad++ when asked (save your work).
3. Select text to be sorted
4. Menu => TextFX Tools => Sort lines * (there's multiple options here)

   [image]

Of course, a [proper editor](http://www.vim.org/) will have this built-in ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search yielded several options for "sorting"

http://www.cleancss.com/

http://www.styleneat.com/

If you are talking about "shortening" your file, then @Sunyatasattva has the correct approach using minification.